# JavaScript objects and dynamic attribute calling

Tags: javascript, oop, object

I have an object that has several attributes that have been dynamically generated with a loop.
It has a structure similar to this :

```
const theObject = {
    "rank1": 23,
    "rank2": 43,
    "rank3": 21,
    "rank4": 29,
    "rank5": 25,
}
```

How can I dynamically get the value of a specific attribute in that object.
for example if I wanted to `console.log(theObject.rank2)` but the "2" is dynamically generated from another object s id. How would I do that?

I tried something like `console.log(theObject.rank+anotherObject.id)` and I got undefined as result.

Comment: just try this : theObject["rank"+anotherObject.id]

Comment: ahh of course! accessing via brackets and concatenation did the trick..  thanks!